# Load PDF in a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, pdf

I've been searching around and I can't find any clean ways to render PDFs in a native WPF application. Most solutions are either paid or run with errors or cannot load PDFs for my particular use case in Civil Construction.

Does WPF have any built in PDF renderers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a built in PDF API in the UWP Runtime under the following nuget package:

```
Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts
```

If you check under [Windows.Data.Pdf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.pdf.pdfdocument?view=winrt-19041) there's actually an example link to GITHub for a very barebones PDF Renderer--that just so happens to be robust enough to load up Civil Construction PDFs: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PdfDocument

Of course the example is running on UWP so you'll need to go into the Windows settings (which should be auto-prompted if you've never installed UWP developer packages) and enable developer mode. This will give VS access to run UWP applications on your computer. You can search "developer" in the Windows settings or they're located under:

```
Settings -> Update & Security -> For developers -> "Developer Mode"
```

For the build platform in the configuration manager change from `ARM` to `x64` (or x86 if you're on a 32-bit machine) and the program should run (works in VS Community 2019).